# PySpark Which Join Should be Selected

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframe:

Dataframe 1

| ID | Account |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | B |

Dataframe 2

| Country | Account |
| --- | --- |
| USA | A |
| UK | A |
| USA | B |
| UK | B |

I would like to join two datafram on Account and each ID in dataframe 1 generate a row in new dataframe like:

| ID | Country | Account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | A |
| 2 | USA | A |
| 1 | UK | A |
| 2 | UK | A |
| 3 | USA | B |
| 4 | USA | B |
| 3 | UK | B |
| 4 | UK | B |

Which join type should I choose?

Comment: Have you tried any of join types and see if that returns what you want?  here is some visual ref if it helps. https://medium.com/@anant30/spark-joins-for-dummies-e9a05020f504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left, right, inner and outer joins all work. It depends on what you want to do with rows that cannot be joined between the tables:

Remove them: inner join

Keep all rows: outer join

Keep only all rows from df1: left join

Keep only all rows from df2: right join